# json is null in makeHttpRequest call in Android

Tags: java, android, json

I have a java web project named ConnectionToOracle . I have a servlet named Sign_Up_Servlet there .

So I have the following code :

```
 private static String url_sign_up_execute
                = "http://10.11.201.84:8084//ConnectionToOracle/Sign_Up_Servlet"; 

private class GetSignUpStatus extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {


        ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Sign_Up.this);

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.show(); 
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);


            pDialog.dismiss();

            if (json == null) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        "Unable to Perform Your Request.Server Is Temporarily  Unreachable! Please Try Later.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } 
            else{
                if(pErrorFlag.equals("N"))
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sign Up successfully done ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                else if( pErrorFlag.equals("Y") )
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), pErrorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }   
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); 
//          params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pDeviceId",deviceId_str));   
//          params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pMobileNo",mobile_no_str)); 
//          params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pUserId",user_id_str)); 
//          params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pPassword",password_str)); 
//          params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pPinCode",pin_code_str));

//          params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pDeviceId","1"));   
//          params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pMobileNo","1")); 
//          params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pUserId","1")); 
//          params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pPassword","1")); 
//          params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pPinCode","1"));
//          
            json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_sign_up_execute, "POST", params);

            // Log.d("All Login Responese: ", json.toString());

            try {
                if (json != null) {
                    jsonArray = json.getJSONArray(TAG_SIGN_UP);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        pErrorFlag = c.getString(TAG_ERROR_FLAG);
                        pErrorMessage = c.getString(TAG_ERROR_MESSAGE) ;

                    }
                    // Log.d("error Code", errorCode);
                } else {
                     Log.d("Server Unreachable",
                     "Unable to Perform Your request.Server Is Unreachable! Please Try Later.");
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

I am making a http request to "http://10.11.201.84:8084//ConnectionToOracle/Sign_Up_Servlet" url . But I am getting json value null . Why ? How can I resolve this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using "http://10.11.201.84:8084/ConnectionToOracle/Sign_Up_Servlet" instead of "http://10.11.201.84:8084//ConnectionToOracle/Sign_Up_Servlet". Probably the problem is an extra "/" after the port number.....